# Android adding multiple arrays to TextViews's in an Array Adapter

Tags: android

Hi i'm trying to populate a list view whose cell has 3 text views i am using an array adapter to do this it does the first textview fine but if i add any more i get this error

```
The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(Activity, int, int, ArrayList<String>, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

heres what i have tried so far i'm creating Arraylists and matching them to the relevant view in the layout

```
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.document_cell, R.id.name, docNamesArray, R.id.doctype, docTypeArray);
              docsList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:padding="10dp" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/docicon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/docicon"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/doctype"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/docicon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/modified"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/docicon"
        android:layout_below="@+id/doctype"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need to create your own ArrayAdapter to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(Activity, int, int, ArrayList<String>, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined
```

Look at the public constructors. Your constructor params do not match any of the below

1. ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource)
2. ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)
3. ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
4. ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
5. ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects)
6. ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List objects)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

You have wrong params for the constructor.

If guess what you need is a Custom ArrayAdapter.

Example

https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to pass in multiple String arrays you should create your own adapter and pass in a List of String arrays